# PDF in shiny application - Nothing appears

Tags: r, shiny

I made the following script to show `1.pdf`, but nothing shows up after clicking on `start`.

Any comments would be great.

Appreciate!

```
shinyApp(
  ui <- function(){
    tagList(tabPanel(""),
            pageWithSidebar(
              headerPanel(
                ""
              ),
              sidebarPanel
              (
              tags$head(tags$style(type="text/css", ".well { max-width: 280px; }")),
              actionButton("strt", label = "Start",style="width:32%;"),
              actionButton("logout", "Logout",style="color: red; width:32%;")       
              ),
              mainPanel(tableOutput('path'))
            )
    )   
  },

  server = (function(input, output,session) {
    observeEvent(input$strt, {
      output$path <- renderUI({tags$iframe(src="E:/shiny/Correct/www/1.pdf",style="height:800px; width:100%;scrolling=yes")})   
    })
  })
)
```

Comment: Well you seem to be trying to use `renderUI()` with a `tableOutput` rather than `uiOutput()`. But you might want to check your browser console for errors. Most browsers will not allow you to access local files on your computer from web pages (it's a security risk). You'd have to actually serve that file from the shiny web server. See this related question for how to do that: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43747737/download-and-display-pdf-in-shiny

Answer (score 1):

I solved it as follows:

```
observeEvent(input$strt, {
    addResourcePath("pdf_folder","E:/shiny/Correct")
    output$path <- renderUI({tags$iframe(src="pdf_folder/1.pdf",style="height:800px; width:100%;scrolling=yes")})
})
```